# Signalr 2.0.0 doesn't behave as previous version

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have updated my server solution to work with MVC 5 and latest version of signalr and have two major issues:

1. I have overriden the `OnConnected` function and it is not being invoked.
2. Messages to client are not being received , calls from the client are being received

this is the client code

```
define(['jquery', 'toastr', 'Q'], function($, toastr, Q) {

var incidentHubProxy;
var deferred = Q.defer();

var connect = function() {
    var connection = $.hubConnection(localStorage.url);
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    incidentHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('notification');

    connection.start()
            .done(function () {
                toastr.success('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
                setInterval(function () {
                    incidentHubProxy.invoke('ping');
                }, 3000);
                deferred.resolve();
            })
            .fail(function () { toastr.error('Could not connect'); });
    incidentHubProxy.on('notify', function (data) {
        toastr.info(data.topic);
        toastr.info(data.data);
    });
    incidentHubProxy.on('pong', function (data) {
        toastr.info('got pong');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

var joinGroup = function (groupName) {
    incidentHubProxy.invoke('joinGroup', groupName);
};



return {
    connect: connect,
    joinGroup: joinGroup
};
});
```

i have updated the code to that and still dont work

define(['jquery', 'toastr', 'Q'], function($, toastr, Q) {

```
var incidentHubProxy;
var deferred = Q.defer();

var connect = function() {
    var connection = $.hubConnection(localStorage.url);
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    incidentHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('notification');

    incidentHubProxy.notify = function(data) {
        toastr.info(data.topic);
        toastr.info(data.data);
    };

    incidentHubProxy.pong = function(data) {
        toastr.info('got pong');
    };

    connection.start()
            .done(function () {
                toastr.success('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
                setInterval(function () {
                    incidentHubProxy.invoke('ping');
                }, 3000);
                deferred.resolve();
            })
            .fail(function () { toastr.error('Could not connect'); });


    return deferred.promise;
};

var joinGroup = function (groupName) {
    incidentHubProxy.invoke('joinGroup', groupName);
};



return {
    connect: connect,
    joinGroup: joinGroup
};
```

});

Comment: It's varied over different versions how much you need to pay heed to the advice for writing a JS client (is that what your client is, you haven't said?): "you must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the `start` method." - are you doing that?

Comment: my client is JS, and also i have upgraded it to signalr 2.0.0, i will post the client code

Comment: And see in your client code how you're registering your event handlers *after* having called `start`?

Comment: updated the code and still dont work

Comment: It should be `incidentHubProxy.client.notify = ...`, not `incidentHubProxy.notify = ...`. Or you could still use the `on()` form. Not sure why you changed it.

Comment: still not works, and still i dont understand why i dont get the onConnected

Comment: ok, i had to clean the browser cache